# Do I have to drop the primary key or reload the table data for partitioning in MySQL InnoDB?

Tags: mysql, innodb, database-performance, database-partitioning, pruning

I have to partition a few tables by date range. Do I have to drop the primary or reload the complete data to be able to partition these tables?

Some of the tables do contain a lot more than 50 million rows.

```
alter table temp_table_test1
partition by range (unix_timestamp(created_at))
(
    partition p01 values less than (unix_timestamp('2015-02-01')),
    partition p02 values less than (unix_timestamp('2015-02-01')),
    partition p03 values less than (unix_timestamp('2015-02-01')),
    partition p04 values less than (unix_timestamp('2015-02-01')),
    partition p02 values less than (maxvalue)
);
```

This is the script I am using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do anything if you have no partitioning yet. According to [this thread](http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?106,264106,264110) this will be done automatically:

> you can use ALTER TABLE to add partitioning to the table,  keep in
>   mind though that this will actually create the  new partitioned table
>   first, then copy over all the  existing data, and finally drop the old
>   unpartitioned  table. So this operation may take a while and will 
>   temporarily use twice the disk space (which in the case  of InnoDB is
>   not given back to the operating system ...)

Comment: Was about to post the answer to this. Got it!